# android get contacts with at least 1 phone number

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I am trying to get all numbers that i have in my device with condition , that the contact contains at least 1 phone number. I made a try , but it doesn't work.

```
selectionString =  edtSearch.getText().toString() ;
String[] selectionArgs = { "%" + selectionString + "%", selectionString + "%", "%" + selectionString, "0"};



String selection =  ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ? OR "
        + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ? OR "
        + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ? AND "
        + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " NOT LIKE ?";


CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(ContactsActivity.this,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, // URI
        null, // projection fields
        selection, // the selection criteria
        selectionArgs, // the selection args
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC" // the sort order
);
return cursorLoader;
```

Where is the mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the selectionArgs and selection as below,

```
String[] selectionArgs = { "%" + selectionString + "%", selectionString + "%", "%" + selectionString};

String selection =  ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ? OR "
            + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ? OR "
            + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ? AND "
            + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "='1'";
```